# Ubuntu install menu just keeps rebooting when I select install - Trying to dual boot Vista and Ubuntu 14.04 with USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

I have made a USB stick to boot Ubuntu using the instructions given here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

When I restart my PC, I get the BIOS, press F12, and choose the option to boot from "USB-Device" which then brings me to the Ubuntu install menu (the one which gives the options: try without installing, install, memtest, help, etc.). If I select "Try without installing" or "Install Ubuntu", the only thing it does is give me a grey screen for 2 seconds them my PC re-boots again and brings me back to where I press F12 (if I don't do anything, Windows always boots up even if I put USB-Device at the top of the list).

It's not installing anything at all or doing anything. It just keeps booting over and over.

I am trying to install from Windows Vista and have a XPS630i (if I remember correctly) which dates from around 2009.

I have read other questions from but found no same issue. Additional question: if I can't get this to work, how would I go about just wiping Windows and using only Ubuntu? Will it most likely work then or should I get the same issue with the USB boot?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how reliable PendriveLinux is, but I've made the best experience with [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Try creating the bootstick with it, and retry booting from it.

PS: [The option "Replace Windows by Ubuntu" does nothing else than to wipe the entire hard drive and install Ubuntu on it.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1265192)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried using Linux Live USB Creator and it seems to work now. I just realized now that I should've tried to reduce the partition size Vista is using thought. I guess PendriveLinux is kind of updated. The menu I was getting seemed kind of dated and was not the same one I am getting now (purple background of Trusty Thar).

Comment: The different boot menus can be from the different tools writing the iso to usb differently. Last time I tried unetbootin it wrote it's own basic boot menu (GRUB I think), while pendrivelinux's tool had the original Ubuntu menu like booting from cd. But if one doesn't work, odds are the other will